# Example of using .match operator in Groovy

Tags: groovy

As a newbie question, granted that a switch statement could be used, can the match operator be used on a list iterator

```
def myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
myList.each {
    it.match {
        case /1/ => println "ONE!"
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like as:

```
def myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
myList.each {
    switch(it) {
        case ~/1/ : println "ONE!"; break
        case ~/2/ : println "TWO!"; break
    }
}
```

(I'm not groovy expert - suggestions are desirable)

Comment: Yes, thanks, that would work. I was looking for an example of the .match operator, can it be used here or otherwise where appropriate?

Comment: There is no match operator in standard groovy... Are you thinking of Ruby?

Comment: Reimeus, can you explain what will you do?

Comment: In eclipse, if you type in 'it.match' the content assist fills in it.match {  case value => } as a match/case statement. Probably not appropriate here? Looking for a a match/case example.

Comment: @Reimeus that's not groovy... :-/

Comment: @tim_yates time to turn off my Scala IDE content assist :D

Answer (score 0):

A groovy way to do it is to use a map of closures:

```
def caseMap = [ 1 : { println "ONE!" },
                2 : { println "TWO!" },
              ]
def myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
myList.each { 
    if (caseMap.containsKey(it)) { 
        caseMap[it]() 
    }
}
```

You may need to put parens around caseMap[it].

Comment: For each item in myList, look up the appropriate action to take in the caseMap, then execute that action (if found in the map).

Comment: Oops. Sorry.  You were looking for a match operator example.